# Custom :hover animation from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im currently filling an element with data that contins spritesheet animations. this animations have custom dimensions so i cant really use any static css. using css3 i managed to define the keyframes like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes play {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: calc(-100% + 32px + 1px); }
}
```

now i want to only play the animation on hover like this

```
.emoticon:hover {
    -webkit-animation: play 1000ms steps(10) infinite;
}
```

but this only works when the spritesheet got 10 frames. what is a good way to do this without creating 100 different classes?

Comment: Take a look at the animation library GSAP.

Comment: [^ GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)

Comment: thanks i will look into it. maybe an alternate way to do it without any external librarys?